# QT socket read losing bytes

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to work with length-preceded TCP messages using Qt. I have following method:

```
QByteArray con::read()
{
    QByteArray s;
    s = _pSocket->read(4);
    if (s.length() == 4) {
        int size = char_to_int32(s);
        s = _pSocket->read(size);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Well, it does not work. Looks like I lose all data after reading first 4 bytes: the first read works fine, but `read(size)` returns nothing. Is there a way to solve this?

The char_to_int32 is:

```
int char_to_int32(QByteArray s)
{
    int size = 0;
    size |= (s.at(0) << 24);
    size |= (s.at(1) << 16);
    size |= (s.at(2) << 8);
    size |= (s.at(3));
    return size;
}
```

**EDIT :**

The sending function (plain C):

```
int send(int connfd, const unsigned char* message, unsigned int size) {
    int c;
    unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char*) malloc(4 + size);
    int32_to_char(size, bytes); // converts message size to 4 bytes
    memcpy(bytes + 4, message, size);
    c = write(connfd, bytes, 4 + size);
    free(bytes);
    if (c <= 0)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

By the way, when I call _pSocket->readAll(), the entire packet is read, including 4-byte size and message itself.

**EDIT :**

```
void int32_to_char(uint32_t in, char* bytes) {
    bytes[0] = (in >> 24) & 0xFF;
    bytes[1] = (in >> 16) & 0xFF;
    bytes[2] = (in >> 8) & 0xFF;
    bytes[3] = in & 0xFF;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the `char_to_int32` function definition?

Comment: what is the size? are you sure it's 32 bit signed int?

Comment: Try to print "size" value before using it in the read(). I bet the problem is there

Comment: Thats the first thing I done. The size value is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using the [`QByteArray QIODevice::read(qint64 maxSize)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#read-2) function, you may not be detecting errors correctly:

> This function has no way of reporting errors; returning an empty QByteArray() can mean either that no data was currently available for reading, or that an error occurred.

Some things to try:

- Use the [`qint64 QIODevice::read(char* data, qint64 maxSize)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#read) which reports errors:

  > If an error occurs ... this function returns -1.
- Call [`QIODevice::errorString`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#errorString) and [`QAbstractSocket::error`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#error) to find out what is going wrong.

  - For bonus points, listen to the `QAbstractSocket::error` error signal.
- If this is a new protocol you are creating, try using [`QDataStream`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html) for serialization, this automatically handles length prefixs and is platform independent. Your `char_to_int32` will break if you mix platforms with different [endienness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and may break between different OSs or compilers as `int` is not guaranteed to be 32 bits (it is defined as [at least 16 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)).

  - If you can't use `QDataStream`, at least use the [htons, ntohs ...](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) functions.

**Edit**

Here is some example code showing hton/ntoh usage. Note that `uint32_t` and not `int` is used as it's guaranteed to be 32 bits. I've also used `memcpy` rather than pointer casts in the encode/decode to prevent aliasing and alignment problems (I've just done a cast in the test function for brevity).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

void encode(uint32_t in, char* out)
{
    /* Host to Network long (32 bits) */
    const uint32_t t = htonl(in);
    memcpy(out, &t, sizeof(t));
}

uint32_t decode(char* in)
{
    uint32_t t;
    memcpy(&t, in, sizeof(t));
    /* Network to Host long (32 bits) */
    return ntohl(t);
}

void test(uint32_t v)
{
    char buffer[4];
    printf("Host Input:  %08x\n", v);
    encode(v, buffer);
    printf("Network:     %08x\n", *((uint32_t*)buffer));
    printf("Host Output: %08x\n\n", decode(buffer));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    test(0);
    test(1);
    test(0x55);
    test(0x55000000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't use QDataStream on a server side. How should I use htonl in my case?  int32_to_char(htonl(in), char* bytes) or some other way?

Comment: Thank you! That's really great example. The main problem was solved too: I've tried to use the read(char* data, qint64 maxSize) and it works even without network byte order. Still have no idea what's wrong with QByteArray QIODevice::read(qint64 maxSize).